# How to extract a List from a Bson Document

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

i'm facing a problem when i want to get a list out of a mongoDb document that i get from this function:
mongoDbAccess.getCollection(collection).find(params).projection(projection);

Problem is my Document has a list of years in it like :

```
{
  "name":"Emily",
  "years":[2019,2016,2015]
}
```

and i can't get the right way to extract the years list easily.

I already tried using

```
List<?> yearList = document.get("years", List.class);
```

but this somehow return null.

i know i always can just get the string out of it and then turns it back into a List but there must be an easier way to do this.
Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just very simple casting trick:

```
List<Integer> yearList = (List<Integer>) document.get("years");
```